# Limit is not working in with method for eager loading YII

Tags: php, yii

Below is my code:-

```
$model = new Library;

$libraries = $model->with(array(
    "assetFolders" => array(
                        "condition" => "parent_id = 0",
                        "order" => "assetFolders.sequence asc",
                        "with" => array("assets" => array("condition" => "folder_id = 153", "limit" => 50))
            )
            )->findAll("owner = :owner and parent_id = :parent_id", array(":owner" => $user_id, ":parent_id" => 0));
```

But the limit is not working in "with" for "assets" relation. If I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't:

When specifying `with` in a DB criteria you are juste asking Yii to perform a SQL query with a join.

So you request will be somehing like

```
SELECT library.*, assetFolders.*, assets.*
FROM library, assetFolders, assets
WHERE  library.id = assetFolders.id_library AND assetFolders.id=assets.id_folder
    AND library.owner = :user_id AND library.parent_id = :parent_id
```

I don't know your columns so this is an aproximate request. (By the way the condition in `assetFolders` isn't needed, it's already applied in the `findAll`)

This query will return has many row has there is assets, then Yii will process the result to set the libraries, the related assetFolders and the related assets

If you specify a `LIMIT` it will always works on the total number of result rows, so in this case the limit will be applied on the whole query and not the related models.